# MySQL Rewrite Query without IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have a large sql query which is generated by some java code. I'm responsible for modifying one tiny portion of this query. The original query looked like this:

```
SELECT
    fields
FROM
    table1, table2, table3
WHERE
    table1.key = table2.key
AND
    table2.key2 = table3.key2
AND
    (field1 = 'x')
AND
    (field2 = 'y')
```

My code area is responsible for appending an additional "AND" query to the existing query. Ideally, the other developers do not want me to adjust the "FROM" clause at all.

For the field2 = 'y' portion, there is now a new table with overriden values that they want to check. So I initially tried to write:

```
AND
    (field2 = 'y' OR table1.key IN (SELECT key from override_table))
```

When I ran the above query, it ran for over 12 hours and had to be manually terminated by a DBA. Interestingly, the override_table is completely empty, so I don't think it is an indexing issue. Our database server is MySQL 5.0 and our IT department refuses to upgrade it to a newer version (upgrades have been requested numerous times and ignored).

I did try to run an explain on the query and there was nothing anomalous that came up. If I remove my 'OR table1.key IN' clause, the query goes back to running promptly. A colleague told me that MySQL 5 struggles with sub-selects. Is there any good way to rewrite the IN clause to avoid sub-selects in MySQL 5? Or any other advice about how to optimize this query?

Thanks.

Comment: Try doing `OR exists (select 1 from override_table where key = table1.key)` instead of `OR table1.key IN (SELECT key from override_table)`

Comment: Don't use comma-joins

Comment: @Strawberry - I agree and prefer standard INNER/LEFT OUTER Joins instead of comma joins, but that isn't something I'm allowed to change

Comment: Change what you are and are not allowed to change.

Comment: @zedfoxus - Thanks for the idea. I tried converting it to an exists and the performance is better.

Comment: I'll add a little more description to my previous comment in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to only change there `where` clause, use this:

```
SELECT
    fields
FROM
    table1, table2, table3
WHERE
    table1.key = table2.key
AND
    table2.key2 = table3.key2
AND
    (field1 = 'x')
AND
    (
        field2 = 'y' 
        OR exists (select 1 from override_table where key = table1.key)
    )
```

Just make sure that override_table.key is indexed and so is table1.key. `EXISTS` will be faster when there are several keys in override_table.

If you have option to test out the queries, try providing [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to the query as well along with `explain` to see how performance varies between hinting and no hinting, `exists` + hinting, `in` + hinting etc.